# apache ode bpel expression count doesn't work

Tags: apache, xpath, count, bpel, ode

Please I need your help, I think that I have read all the threads related to apache ode, I'm either blind or stupid cause I've looked everywhere but it seems like no one has ever had a problem with count

I have an input sequence (int array) and I use a loop to do a simple addition of its content, but the count on the sequence is always returning 1. This is driving me crazy please someone help me with this

I use eclipse luna, bpel designer plugin, tomcat 8, apache ode beta 2 (because of the inline from spec initialization variables)
I don't know what details I can add here, so if I have to add more info just tell me and I'll do it

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
Thanks Walker. I tried a simple test, I just wanted to assign the count on sequence. Here is my assign :

```
<bpel:copy>
   <bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
         <![CDATA[count($input.payload/tns:input)]]>
    </bpel:from>
    <bpel:to part="payload" variable="output">
         <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:result]]></bpel:query>
     </bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the code you have tried? Can't see what is going wrong without seeing what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Walker. I've added the code I use to get the count

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like the problem is caused by xpath 1.0 it doesn't handle sequences, do you know how to configure bpel design to generate a process with xpath 2.0 ?